# How parse JSON from 2 URLs properly?

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I need to parse JSON from 2 different URL's

```
let jsonUrlStr1 = "https://123"
let jsonUrlStr2 = "https://325"

guard let url1 = URL(string: jsonUrlStr1) else { return }
guard let url2 = URL(string: jsonUrlStr2) else { return }
```

Here I'm running session for 1st url:

```
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url1) { (data, response, err) in

        if err != nil {
            print("Error:\(String(describing: err))")
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {

      let myData1 = try JSONDecoder().decode(SomeJsonModel1.self, from: data)

            //Some code

        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error:\(jsonErr)")
        }

        }.resume()//URLSession
```

And then again, I'm running another session for 2nd url, using the same way:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url2) { (data, response, err) in

    if err != nil {
        print("Error:\(String(describing: err))")
    }

    guard let data = data else { return }

    do {

  let myData2 = try JSONDecoder().decode(SomeJsonModel2.self, from: data)

        //Some code

    } catch let jsonErr {
        print("Error:\(jsonErr)")
    }

    }.resume()//URLSession
```

This code works and I get the result.
But I think **there should be a more correct way** to parse 2 URLs.
Please advise how to do it correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using **completion block** like this :

```
func getDataFromJson(url: String, completion: @escaping (_ success: [String : Any]) -> Void) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { Data, response, error in

            guard let data = Data, error == nil else {  // check for fundamental networking error

                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {  // check for http errors

                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print(response!)
                return

            }

            let responseJSON  = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String : Any]
            completion(responseJSON)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

and call method like this :

```
    let jsonUrlStr1 = "https://123"
    let jsonUrlStr2 = "https://325"

    getDataFromJson(url: jsonUrlStr1, completion: { response in
       print("JSON response for url1 :: ",response) // once jsonUrlStr1 get it's response call next API 

       getDataFromJson(url: jsonUrlStr2, completion: { response in
           print("JSON response for url2 :: ",response)
       })

    })
```